# Writing binary in python and read in c++

Tags: python, c++

writing binary in python.

```py
# curr_feat is **numpy array**
# curr_feat's shape is **(64,)**
# curr_feat dtype is **float64**
"""
array([1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
       1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
"""
curr_feat.tofile(f)
```

read in C++

```cpp
fp=fopen(feat_file,"rb");
fread(tmp.data(),(maxDim)*sizeof(bool),1,fp);
fclose(fp);
```

read value is different from write value.

What should I do to write/read correctly?

Comment: If you're writing doubles why are you reading bools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `fread` doesn't look right.  Try this:

```
fread(tmp.data(),sizeof(double),maxDim,fp);
```

This assumes that `tmp` is `std::vector<double>` and you've already resized it to `maxDim`.  Trying to read into a `vector` that is not of sufficient size would be undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you. You're so helpful!
It works when I change my python array type as bool!

Answer (score 0):

[`tofile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tofile.html) is written as a text file by default. Use

```py
curr_feat.tofile(f, sep='') # empty sep
```

to write as binary.

Comment: Since the default for `sep` is `""`, isn't that what they're already doing?